# Im trying to use SolidColorBrush but getting many Cannot convert type errors how can i fix it and use the SolidColorBrush?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the tope of form1 i did:

```
using System.Windows.Media;
```

But then everywhere in my code where i used Pen Brush Color i had to add before it System.Drawing for example:

```
System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Green, 2f))
```

If i will not do it i will get an error for example:

```
System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Green, 2f))
```

Error   2   'Color' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Drawing.Color' and 'System.Windows.Media.Color'

So i add System.Drawing before it and no errors on this lines.

The problem is when im trying to use SolidColorBrush in my method thats why i needed to add the Media class:

```
private void DrawText(string text, System.Drawing.Color pen_color, System.Windows.Media.Color brushes_color, Graphics graphics, int point1, int point2, Point point3)
        {
            SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(brushes_color);
            System.Drawing.Color color = ((System.Windows.Media.Brushes)brush).Color;
            using (System.Drawing.Pen pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(pen_color, 6f))
            {
                Point pt1 = new Point(point1); // 369, 90
                Point pt2 = new Point(point2); // 469, 90
                graphics.DrawLine(pen, pt1, pt2);
            }

            graphics.DrawString(text,
                    this.Font, (System.Drawing.Brushes)brush, point3); // 480, 83
        }
```

Im getting some errors:

On this line: System.Drawing.Brushes

Error   5   Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Brushes' to 'System.Drawing.Brush'

On: point3

Error   6   Argument 4: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Point' to 'System.Drawing.RectangleF'

On this line: (System.Drawing.Brushes)brush

Error   3   Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush' to 'System.Drawing.Brushes'

On this line: System.Drawing.Color color = ((System.Windows.Media.Brushes)brush).Color;

Error   2   Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brushes'

On this part: graphics.DrawString

Error   4   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString(string, System.Drawing.Font, System.Drawing.Brush, System.Drawing.RectangleF)' has some invalid arguments

And the property Color is not exist: System.Windows.Media.Color brushes_color

Error   1   The type name 'Color' does not exist in the type 'System.Drawing.Brush'

All i wanted to do is to make that the user will be able to select the Brushes Color on this line:

```
graphics.DrawString(text,
                    this.Font, (System.Drawing.Brushes)brush, point3);
```

In the original the line was:

```
graphics.DrawString(text,
                    this.Font, Brushes.Green , point3);
```

But i want that the use will select the Color of the Brushes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is when im trying to use SolidColorBrush in my method thats why i needed to add the Media class

You don't need that. The class in `System.Drawing` is called [`SolidBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.drawing.solidbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Remove the `System.Windows.Media` reference.